# I got tow tutorials in C# one to enrol face image and the second to be converted into ISO features. How to combine them into one program?

Tags: c#

I got tow tutorials in C# one to enrol face image and the second to be converted into biomedic ISO features. How to combine them into one application? So I can read the image and get the biometric feature at the same time.

The first

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using Neurotec.Biometrics;
using Neurotec.Biometrics.Client;
using Neurotec.Licensing;

namespace Neurotec.Tutorials
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int Usage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("usage:");
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0} [input file] [output template] [still image or video file]", TutorialUtils.GetAssemblyName());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\t[input file]  - image filename or video file with face.");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[template] - filename to store face template.");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[still image or video file] - specifies that passed source parameter is image (value: 0) or video (value: 1)");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\texample: {0} image.jpg template.dat 0", TutorialUtils.GetAssemblyName());
            Console.WriteLine("\texample: {0} video.avi template.dat 1", TutorialUtils.GetAssemblyName());
            Console.WriteLine();
            return 1;
        }

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            string components = "Biometrics.FaceExtraction";
            const string AdditionalComponents = "Biometrics.FaceSegmentsDetection";

            TutorialUtils.PrintTutorialHeader(args);

            if (args.Length < 3)
            {
                return Usage();
            }

            try
            {
                if (!NLicense.ObtainComponents("/local", 5000, components))
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Could not obtain licenses for components: {0}", components));
                }
                if (NLicense.ObtainComponents("/local", 5000, AdditionalComponents))
                {
                    components += "," + AdditionalComponents;
                }

                bool isVideo = false;

                using (var biometricClient = new NBiometricClient())
                using (var subject = new NSubject())
                using (var face = new NFace())
                {
                    // Read face image from file and add it to NFace object
                    face.FileName = args[0];

                    if (args.Length > 2)
                        isVideo = args[2] == "1";

                    //define that the face source will be a stream
                    face.CaptureOptions = isVideo ? NBiometricCaptureOptions.Stream : NBiometricCaptureOptions.None;

                    // Read face image from file and add it NSubject
                    subject.Faces.Add(face);

                    //Set face template size (recommended, for enroll to database, is large) (optional)
                    biometricClient.FacesTemplateSize = NTemplateSize.Large;

                    // Detect all faces features
                    bool isAdditionalComponentActivated = NLicense.IsComponentActivated(AdditionalComponents);
                    biometricClient.FacesDetectAllFeaturePoints = isAdditionalComponentActivated;

                    // Create template from added face image
                    var status = biometricClient.CreateTemplate(subject);
                    if (status == NBiometricStatus.Ok)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Template extracted");
                        // Save compressed template to file
                        File.WriteAllBytes(args[1], subject.GetTemplateBuffer().ToArray());
                        Console.WriteLine("template saved successfully");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Extraction failed: {0}", status);
                        return -1;
                    }

                    // Get detection details if the face was detected
                    foreach (var nface in subject.Faces)
                    {
                        foreach (var attributes in nface.Objects)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("face:");
                            Console.WriteLine("\tlocation = ({0}, {1}), width = {2}, height = {3}",
                            attributes.BoundingRect.X, attributes.BoundingRect.Y, attributes.BoundingRect.Width, attributes.BoundingRect.Height);
                            if (attributes.RightEyeCenter.Confidence > 0 || attributes.LeftEyeCenter.Confidence > 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\tfound eyes:");
                                if (attributes.RightEyeCenter.Confidence > 0)
                                    Console.WriteLine("\t\tRight: location = ({0}, {1}), confidence = {2}",
                                        attributes.RightEyeCenter.X, attributes.RightEyeCenter.Y,
                                        attributes.RightEyeCenter.Confidence);
                                if (attributes.LeftEyeCenter.Confidence > 0)
                                    Console.WriteLine("\t\tLeft: location = ({0}, {1}), confidence = {2}",
                                        attributes.LeftEyeCenter.X, attributes.LeftEyeCenter.Y,
                                        attributes.LeftEyeCenter.Confidence);
                            }
                            if (isAdditionalComponentActivated && attributes.NoseTip.Confidence > 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\tfound nose:");
                                Console.WriteLine("\t\tlocation = ({0}, {1}), confidence = {2}", attributes.NoseTip.X, attributes.NoseTip.Y, attributes.NoseTip.Confidence);
                            }
                            if (isAdditionalComponentActivated && attributes.MouthCenter.Confidence > 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\tfound mouth:");
                                Console.WriteLine("\t\tlocation = ({0}, {1}), confidence = {2}", attributes.MouthCenter.X, attributes.MouthCenter.Y, attributes.MouthCenter.Confidence);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return TutorialUtils.PrintException(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                NLicense.ReleaseComponents(components);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using Neurotec.Images;
using Neurotec.Biometrics.Standards;
using Neurotec.Licensing;

namespace Neurotec.Tutorials
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int Usage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("usage: {0} [FCRecord] {{[image]}}", TutorialUtils.GetAssemblyName());
            Console.WriteLine("\t[FCRecord] - output FCRecord");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[image]    - one or more images");

            return 1;
        }

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string Components = "Biometrics.Standards.Faces";

            TutorialUtils.PrintTutorialHeader(args);

            if (args.Length < 2)
            {
                return Usage();
            }

            FCRecord fc = null;
            try
            {
                if (!NLicense.ObtainComponents("/local", 5000, Components))
                {
                    throw new NotActivatedException(string.Format("Could not obtain licenses for components: {0}", Components));
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++)
                {
                    using (NImage imageFromFile = NImage.FromFile(args[i]))
                    using (NImage image = NImage.FromImage(NPixelFormat.Grayscale8U, 0, imageFromFile))
                    {
                        if (fc == null)
                        {
                            // Specify standard and version to be used
                            fc = new FCRecord(BdifStandard.Iso, FCRecord.VersionIso30);
                        }
                        FcrFaceImage img = new FcrFaceImage(fc.Standard, fc.Version);
                        img.SetImage(image);
                        fc.FaceImages.Add(img);
                    }
                }
                if (fc != null)
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes(args[0], fc.Save().ToArray());

                    Console.WriteLine("FCRecord saved to {0}", args[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("no images were added to FCRecord");
                }

                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return TutorialUtils.PrintException(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (fc != null)
                {
                    fc.Dispose();
                }

                NLicense.ReleaseComponents(Components);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

make a new Program class with a new Main

Rename first Program class to Code1, Change Main to DoCode1

Rename second Program class to Code2, Change Main to DoCode2

Make you new Main call Code.DoCode1, and Code2.DoCode2

Put all 3 files in one c# project

Profit